# Why can't we do this to reach absolute zero?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, cooling

I have seen the argument that one cannot reach absolute zero in a finite number of steps. For instance on Wikipedia, it states

> It is impossible by any procedure, no matter how idealized, to reduce the temperature of any closed system to zero temperature in a finite number of finite operations.

This is explained using a diagram which shows that a series of entropy and temperature lowering steps cannot get to zero temperature:
[image]

But what about if I used a different experimental technique that amounted to taking steps in the $T, S$ plane at a certain slope? Could I not then reach zero temperature in finite steps? As in
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $0K$ impossible to reach if the heat capacity goes to $0$ as $T$ approaches $0 K$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280180/why-is-0k-impossible-to-reach-if-the-heat-capacity-goes-to-0-as-t-approach)

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine I don't think so? How does this answer rule out the third diagram I provided?

Comment: You have drawn an arbitrary diagram and it does not represent any actual process you can make.  Just drawing a diagram does not make something possible.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine Yes but I have no reason to expect a priori that such a thing can't be done and so the argument doesn't seem complete